# Error FS0039: namespace or module 'AppConfig' is not defined in shared project xamarin

Tags: xamarin, f#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have a shared project and a iOS, Android and Console project.

I have a DbClient.fs that call AppConfig.fs inside the shared project, however if I compile the iOS or Android project I get:

```
../DbClient.fs(39,39): Error FS0039: The value, namespace, type or module 'AppConfig' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:   Config   AppContext (FS0039) (Cobros.Droid)
```

This is a sample of the code:

```
DbClient.fs

module DbClient
..
..
    let _buildDeb(con, deuda:DebtRecord, after:Int64) =
        let cobro = Zone.queryByName(AppConfig.defaultZone())
```

AppConfig.fs

```
module AppConfig

open Plugin.Settings
open Plugin.Settings.Abstractions
...
let defaultZone() =
    read("zone", "Sample").ToUpper()
```

Comment: Are `DbClient` and `AppConfig` in the same project, and if so, is the order correct?

Comment: In the same project. Shared project don't allow to change order.

Comment: So does `AppConfig` come _before_ `DbClient` or _after_?

Answer (score 1):

After the comment of @Fyodor Soikin I recheck.

In the Visual Stuid Mac files were in alphabetic order and reorder it using the IDE not change anything.

So I change the order directly in the xml `.projitems` file and now it compile!